# Adding class with click and capturing added class

Tags: javascript, jquery

After the page is loaded, I can add a class with jquery as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent").click(function(){
        $(".child").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

but I can't catch the click on the added class, it doesn't work.

```
$(".child.active").click(function(){
    alert('this is clicked');
});
```

would you please help me.

Comment: that didn't work :(

Comment: Oh, interesting, I would've thought it would've done a `.closest` or an `event.target.matches` check (both of which would've detected the click), but it doesn't. Guess a different approach is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the child isn't `.active` when the DOM loads, `.child.active` does not select any elements, so the event handler to the child isn't added. Add the handler to the `.child` alone instead, and inside the handler, check if it's active:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parent").click(function() {
    $(".child").addClass("active");
  });
});

$('.child').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    console.log('this is clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

Or add the listener inside the parent click handler instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parent").click(function() {
    $(".child")
      .addClass("active")
      .off('click')
      .on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is('.active')) {
          console.log('this is clicked');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```